# Pandas get_dummies Join causes columns overlap

Tags: pandas

I have the following code which joins `get_dummies` results:

```
mobile_companies = self.df["cell_phone"].str.get_dummies(sep="、").astype(bool)
self.df = self.df.join(mobile_companies)
```

which arise the following error:

```
raise ValueError(f"columns overlap but no suffix specified: {to_rename}")
ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['au'], dtype='object')
```

I tried to change the `join` to `concat` but that creates two columns for `au` column which are `au` and `au.1`. Where `au.1` actually contains the authentic values, and `au` column only contains 0 for all records.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Either [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) your column in the original DataFrame:

```
mobile_companies = self.df["cell_phone"].str.get_dummies(sep="、").astype(bool)
self.df = self.df.drop('au', axis=1).join(mobile_companies)
```

Or [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the DataFrame before joining:

```
mobile_companies = self.df["cell_phone"].str.get_dummies(sep="、").astype(bool)
self.df = self.df.rename(columns={'au': 'new_col'}).join(mobile_companies)
```